# Authorization and user microservices design

Tags: microservices

I'm trying to design microservice from an existing application with a quite standard user management: has authentication and authorization, and stores user data.

I'm developping an *Authorization server* to manage user **authentication** and **authorization** using `OAuth2` as authorization. On other side I have to store user's information/profile.

**Question:** Should *Authorization server* manage:

- **both authorization and user API?** Thus other microservices can contact *Authorization server* on `/me` to get current user but also `/users` to get full list of users.
- **Or only authorization and I have to create *User microservices*?** Thus *Authorization server* only exposes `/me` API related to user and *User microservices* will expose `/users`?

The first solution is a bit simpler but the *Authorization server* will become less generic (less reusable) because user application data model will be part of it (database data model of `User` table).

---

The other requirement is ***Authorization server* should check if a user exists before authorizing it**.

There is no user auto-creation, users must be invited by *administrator* to get access.
With this requirement, the first solution is simple because *Authorization server* has access to user database but the second solution *Authorization server* implies:

1. Share database with *User service* (hum don't like that)
2. Call *User service* before authorization using REST API (for example)
3. *Authorization server* should maintain minimal `User` table (can be renamed `Account`) and administrator will not create user on *User service* but only user account on *Authorization server*

I think **1.** solution is out but any advices about **2.** and **3.**?

**3.** in first place seems the best, but if I want to switch to another *Authorization server*, for example a public one (OAuth2) like Google, Github, Facebook, etc... Security can be compromise because we can't control user account creation.

Any feedback?

Comment: How are you managing authentication?

Comment: External service (based on CAS) is in charge of authentication. But I'm not owner of this service. However, you can simply that by using basic form authentication based on database user info

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, OAuth2 will only give you authorization. But I have seen some solution combining OAuth2 with another protocol / Technology, e.g. Oauth2 + OpenID Connect (OIDC).

To answer to you question, my experience says that it's better to separate authentication from authorisation, as I might be different Services (or Providers). You could use Google or Github for the OAuth2, or AWS Cognito for Auth2+OpenIDConnect. Another known Provider with These two common Technologies (OAuth2+OIDC) is Okta.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple options here, hence please provide more details. e.g. Are you able to use ready-made Authorization server implementation (open source)? What technology are you based on?

I was able to easily integrate IdentityServer (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3), and plug it into own "users" service with simple implementation of a few interfaces. It may also handle the DB hardwork for you (store all data around for OAuth 2.0, like clients with secrets, auth codes etc.). IdentityServer allows you to provide your own link to have the 'register' operation available for users, you may also have ability for Administrator to accept or reject registrations, so only accepted users will be able to log in.

In general - Implementing Authorization Service as it is required by RFC for OAuth2.0 (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749 for details) is never piece of cake. Rather use proven solution when needed.

Regards!